# Make createElement return function/true for fake tag

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, casperjs

How can I make return "Function" for this request:

```
document.createElement("MY_FAKE_TAG").canThisRun
```

Now its return: undefined

Comment: would yoiu explain more details what do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the [`HTMLUnknownElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement)'s prototype, but I really wonder if it's a good idea...

```js
HTMLUnknownElement.prototype.canThisRun = function(){console.log('hi')};

document.createElement('foo').canThisRun();
```

Comment: HTMLUnknownElement.prototype.canThisRun = function(){ return function gavno(){} };

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```js
var element = document.createElement("MY_FAKE_TAG");
element.canThisRun = (function(){
    //your logic here then return
    return true;
})();
console.log( element.canThisRun );
```